# Read img medical image without header in matlab

Tags: matlab, endianness, medical

I have a radiograph .img file without the header file. However, the researchers who have published the file have given this information about it

```
High resolution (2048 x 2048 matrix size, 0.175mm pixel size)
Wide density range (12bit, 4096 gray scale)
Universal image format (no header, big-endian raw data)
```

Using this information, I tried fread command in Matlab to read the image into Matlab.

```
fid = fopen('image.img','r','B');
oneSlice = fread(fid, [2048 2048], '*uint8','B');
imshow(oneSlice)
```

However the resulting image is coming up as incorrect. Is there something that I am doing wrong ? Could someone suggest any different method to read this image file ?

Comment: You need to read it as 16bit, not 8bit, as it contains 12bit data. Try `'*uint16'` instead. Also I'm not sure if `'B'` is accepted, as the documentation says to use `'b'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lung x-rays of the JSRT database (www.jsrt.or.jp/jsrt-db/eng.php), have that format. I tested this code with them and it works:

```
fid = fopen('image.img','r','b');
oneSlice = fread(fid, [2048 2048], '*uint16','b');
img = mat2gray(oneSlice, [0,4096]);
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%%% Read image
    fid = fopen('image.img','r','b');
    oneSlice = fread(fid, [2048 2048], '*uint16','b');
    img = mat2gray(oneSlice, [0,4096]);
    fclose(fid);

%%%rotate image

    imgR = imrotate(img,270);

%%%horizontal flip image

    imgRF = flipdim(TestImgR ,2);
```