# How to read .img files in python?

Tags: python, image, gdal

I have an image in format `.img` and I want to open it in python. How can I do it?

I have an interference pattern in `*.img` format and I need to process it. I tried to open it using GDAL, but I have an error:

```
ERROR 4: `frame_064_0000.img' not recognized as a supported file format.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read .img medical image without header in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946436/read-img-medical-image-without-header-in-python)

Comment: The suffix `img` does not indicate any special format. Do you have information about the format used?

Comment: @KlausD. I have an example of such file in txt format, it consist of some columns of float values

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev, i have already tried this method, but it displayed completely wrong

Comment: Please share the image and anything you know about it - e.g. height, width, number of channels (RGB/greyscale)...

Comment: @MarkSetchell. So, it is grayscale, height - 1024, width - 1024. That's all what I know about this file

Comment: Please share the image too... Google Drive, Dropbox...

Comment: @MarkSetchell, [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HQvGrOpst3MF96vm0OFpzJuTMaALs4h2)

Comment: Does this look correct? http://thesetchells.com/StackOverflow/fringes.jpg

Comment: @MarkSetchell,yes!! How you did it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your image is 1,024 x 1,024 pixels, that would make 1048576 bytes, if the data are 8-bit. But your file is 2097268 bytes, which is just a bit more than double the expected size, so I guessed your data are 16-bit, i.e. 2 bytes per pixel. That means there are 2097268-(2*1024*1024), i.e. 116 bytes of other junk in the file. Folks normally store that extra stuff at the start of the file. So, I just took the last 2097152 bytes of your file and assumed that was a 16-bit greyscale image at 1024x1024.

You can do it at the command-line in Terminal with ImageMagick like this:

```
magick -depth 16 -size 1024x1024+116 gray:frame_064_0000.img -auto-level result.png
```

[image]

In Python, you could open the file, seek backwards 2097152 bytes from the end of the file and read that into a 1024x1024 np.array of uint16.

That will look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

filename = 'frame_064_0000.img' 

# set width and height 
w, h = 1024, 1024 

with open(filename, 'rb') as f: 
    # Seek backwards from end of file by 2 bytes per pixel 
    f.seek(-w*h*2, 2) 
    img = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint16).reshape((h,w)) 

# Save as PNG, and retain 16-bit resolution
Image.fromarray(img).save('result.png')

# Alternative to line above - save as JPEG, but lose 16-bit resolution
Image.fromarray((img>>8).astype(np.uint8)).save('result.jpg')
```

Comment: so, should the python code look like this: ` import numpy as np
f = open("frame_064_0000.img")
arr = np.array(f,np.dtype("uint16")) `