# How to read .img format image?

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a image in .img format. The image size is 1920x1200 px. It's a RGB image with 8 bit depth. I am using the following python code to recover this image. However, the error can display the image but the image content isn't correct. I don't where did I do wrong. Anyone can help?

```
w, h = 1920, 1200   # img image size in px

# read img files and save them to png
with open(file_add, 'rb') as f:
    # Seek backwards from end of file by 3 bytes per pixel
    f.seek(-w*h*3, 2)
    img = np.fromfile(f, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((h, w, 3))

# Save as PNG, and retain 8-bit resolution
PIL.Image.fromarray(img).save('result.png')
```

I would like to upload the `img` file, however, it's larger than the 2Mb limitation.

Comment: Have you tried loading it directly using PIL, for example `PIL.Image.open(file_add)`?

Comment: "I would like to upload the img file, however, it's larger than the 2Mb limitation." Can you make a smaller file that causes the same problem? "However, it can't be recovered correctly." What does that mean? What happens when you run the code, and how is that different from what is supposed to happen? If for example it runs successfully but the `result.png` looks wrong, qualitatively what is wrong with it?

Comment: `.img` doesn't really tell you a file format. For example, the order of the channels can vary; or instead of storing each pixel's data together, it could store separate colour planes. Is there some documentation available from the source of the file?

Comment: There are several different kinds of [files with an `.img` extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMG_(file_format)), but none of them are for graphical images per se — which appears to be what you're expecting. Please [edit] your question and specify what the format of the data is in these files.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice. Yes, the img file can be opened with the code I posted, but the image is incorrect. @KarlKnechtel, I don't have the documentation from the source of the file. I also tried to just read one color plane out, but it still gives me a wrong image. The img file has been uploaded there. Anyone can help to recover it correctly? Thanks

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4RogBH0apq77Nfq1jKfOkEUqCcMbvgl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide better information about the file - why do you think the contained image has those dimensions? It seems unlikely that it is a straightforward image since it contains intelligible words both at the beginning and the end - such as *"pin not in contact"*, *"default pixel"* and *"Data Object"*.

Comment: hi Mark, thanks for pointing out. I missed the 'default pixel' string at the end of the file. This a microscope image saved in a .img format. When the image is saved in raw TIFF, it's a RGB image with 8 bit depth. that's why I assume the .img should have similar information. So,  is there still a way to recover it? Thanks

Comment: Presumably you know the make and model of the microscope and the software used to create the file, so why not make life easier for people trying to help you by providing links to the hardware and software? If you have the same image available as a TIFF, why not make that available too so that people know what they are looking for?

Comment: Hi, Mark. Sorry, this img file is not taken by me, so I don't have the information of the hardware and software exactly. I have a jpg file as the link below. The img. file needs to be recovered will be similar as this. Hope this could help. Thanks again.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12AFzEvjjH384yIqjfG_lRe_8t-tz-kwC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is in some hideous, Microsoft-designed *"Compound File Binary Format"* which is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_File_Binary_Format). I don't run Windows so I cannot unpack it. There are apparently tools available, but I cannot vouch for any of them:

https://openrpmsgfile.com/cfbf.html

http://fileformats.archiveteam.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compound_File

There seems to be a Python module called [olefile](https://olefile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Howto.html#import-olefile) that can read these things. I installed it and was able to test your file and find your image within it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import olefile
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open file
ole = olefile.OleFileIO('image.img')

# Get a directory listing
ole.dumpdirectory()                                                                        

# Open image stream within file and read
stream = ole.openstream('image/__102/DataObject')
data   = stream.read()

# Define image width, height and bytes per pixel
w, h, bpp = 1920, 1200, 3
imsize    = w * h * bpp

# Check data size and image size
print(f'Data size: {len(data)}, Image size: {imsize}')

# There are 192 bytes difference, assume it is a header and take our bytes from the tail of the file
data = data[-imsize:]

# Make into Numpy array
na = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((h*3,w))

# Convert from interleaved by line to interleaved by plane
R = na[0::3]
G = na[1::3]
B = na[2::3]
na = np.dstack((R,G,B))

# Make into PIL Image and save, but you could equally use OpenCV or scikit-image here
Image.fromarray(na).save('result.jpg')
```

[image]

---

Sample Output from running script:

```
'Root Entry' (root) 192 bytes 
  'NonDataObjects' (stream) 26 bytes 
  'Signature' (stream) 12 bytes 
  'image' (storage) 
    '__102' (storage) 
      'DataObject' (stream) 6912192 bytes 
      'DataObjectChilds' (stream) 4 bytes 
      'DataObjectStub' (stream) 6760 bytes 
Data size: 6912192, Image size: 6912000
```

---

I worked out it was a CFBF file from the following. Firstly, if you run the Linux/Unix `file` command to determine the type of the file, you get this:

```
file image.img
image.img: Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info
```

Secondly, if you dump the file with `xxd` you will see the CFBF signature bytes referred to in the links above:

```
xxd image.img
00000000: d0cf 11e0 a1b1 1ae1 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

**Keywords**: OLE file, CFBF, Composite Document File V2 Document, IMG format, d0cf11e0a1b1

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946436/read-img-medical-image-without-header-in-python) post seems to be accomplishing what you're looking for. It reads the data with matplotlib instead, but it should still be able to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I saw this post, but it doesn't do work correctly for my file. I think this works for the file without header? I have posted the link of my .img file. Please try to recover it if possible. Thank you

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4RogBH0apq77Nfq1jKfOkEUqCcMbvgl/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can use if you have in case .img with .hdr nibabel or simpleITK and transformed to numpy array
important !!  simplITK support maximum 5D.

```
import nibabel as nib 
data_path="sample/path"
array_data=nib.load(data_path).get_fdata() # you get your matrix 
print(array_data.shape)
```

exemple with SimpleITK

```
import SimpleITK as sitk 
data_path="/your/path"
imgObj=sitk.Image(data_path) # you will get and Image object it's a complex data format to handle 
array_data = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(imgObj) # you array matrix
```